# ButterKnife @onClick method for Button view is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-button, butterknife

I was updating an existing code by introducing dismiss button, and the onClick Butterknife method is not working for dismiss button, whereas its working for close button. In the below code, I am enabling the close button for some devices and for other devices I am enabling the dismiss button. I am quite unsure why this "dismiss" button is not working, whereas the close button is working fine. And both of them use the ButterKnife, onClick method - onSkip()

InfoActivity.java :

```
public class InfoActivity extends BccActiviy {
  @BindView(R.id.ImageView_CloseView)
  ImageView tCloseView;

  @BindView(R.id.Dismiss)
  Button tDismiss;
  .....


    @OnClick({R.id.Dismiss, R.id.ImageView_CloseView})
    public void onSkip(View v) {
        onDissmissPressed();
    }

    public void initialize(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (tConfig.isDismiss()) {
        tCloseView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        tDismiss.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        tDismiss.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    }

}
```

info_screen.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:ignore="All"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:background="@color/fd_theme"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView_CloseView"
            style="@style/CancelButton"
            android:layout_width="@di/target_size"
            android:layout_marginTop="@di/p_6"
            android:layout_height="@di/target_size"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/close_btn_txt"
            android:importantForAccessibility="yes"
            android:paddingStart="@di/p_14"
            android:paddingEnd="@di/p_14"
            android:background="?attr/bg_color"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/icn_close_white"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/TextView_Layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/TextContent"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@di/size_2x"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@di/rating"
                android:textAlignment="center"/>

            <com.package.button.star.views.widgets.StaView
                android:id="@+id/StarView_AppRating"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_gravity="center">
            </com.package.button.star.views.widgets.StarView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Dismiss"
                style="@style/buttonStyle"
                android:layout_marginTop="@di/margin_top"
                android:paddingLeft="@di/padding_50"
                android:paddingTop="@di/padding_18"
                android:paddingRight="@di/padding_50"
                android:paddingBottom="@di/padding_18"
                android:text="Dismiss"
                android:onClick="onSkip"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="@di/dismiss_fontSize"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:focusable="true"
                tools:text="Dismiss" />

            <ViewStub
                android:id="@+id/actions_stub"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="@di/margin_center"
                android:inflatedId="@+id/view_actions"
                android:layout="@layout/view_actions" />

        </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: `InfoActivity extends XXX` what exactly is `XXX`?

Comment: It extends another activty.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the onClick from xml.